# How can I use this method in other classes?

Tags: c#

I have this class, who contains a method to look around of an object:

```
internal class Game
{
    private IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> PositionsInReach(int row, int column, int distance)
    {
        var visited = new bool[park.GetLength(0),park.GetLength(1)];
        visited[row, column] = true;

        var queue = new Queue<Tuple<int, int>>();
        queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<int, int>(row,column));

        while (queue.Count!=0)
        {
            var aux = queue.Dequeue();
            yield return aux;
            foreach (var adjacentPosition in AdjacentPositions(aux.Item1,aux.Item2))
            {
                if (!visited[adjacentPosition.Item1, adjacentPosition.Item2]
                    && Distance(row,column,aux.Item1,aux.Item2) <= distance)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(adjacentPosition);
                    visited[adjacentPosition.Item1, adjacentPosition.Item2] = true;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> AdjacentPositions(int row, int col)
    {
        if(row+1 < park.GetLength(0)) yield return new Tuple<int,int>(row + 1, col); 
        if(row-1 >=0 ) yield return new Tuple<int,int>(row - 1, col); 
        if(col+1 < park.GetLength(1)) yield return new Tuple<int,int>(row , col + 1);
        if(col - 1 >= 0) yield return new Tuple<int, int>(row , col - 1);
    }

    private static int Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
    {
        return Math.Abs(x2 - x1) + Math.Abs(y2 - y1);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> PositionsInReach2(int row, int column, int distance) //actionrange
    {
        var visited = new bool[park.GetLength(0), park.GetLength(1)];
        visited[row, column] = true;

        var queue = new Queue<Tuple<int, int>>();
        queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<int, int>(row, column));

        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var aux = queue.Dequeue();
            yield return aux;
            foreach (var adjacentPosition in AdjacentPositions(aux.Item1, aux.Item2))
            {
                if (!visited[adjacentPosition.Item1, adjacentPosition.Item2]
                    && Distance(row, column, aux.Item1, aux.Item2) <= distance && park[adjacentPosition.Item1,adjacentPosition.Item2]==null)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(adjacentPosition);
                    visited[adjacentPosition.Item1, adjacentPosition.Item2] = true;
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

So I need to use those methods in other class called Behaviour:

```
    public class EatingBehaviour
    {
        public static bool ToEat1(Dinosaur dino, int x, int y, LivingThing[,] park)
        {
            if (dino.Weight < dino.MiddleWeight  /*&& Dinosaur in action range, I need use the methods of the class Game here*/)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
```

How Can I do that???

Comment: the methods you want... they are private... 
if you have to use them outside the object, they need to be public...

Comment: Make the Game class and it's methods public.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `PositionsInReach` and `AdjacentPositions` are private...
if you have to use them outside of `Game`, they need to be public...

Besides, if you want to use `Game` in another assembly, instead of internal, your class should be public.

Have a look at some definition of C# visibility: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/visibility/

> public - the member can be reached from anywhere. This is the least restrictive visibility. Enums and interfaces are, by default, publicly visible.
>
> protected - members can only be reached from within the same class, or from a class which inherits from this class.
>
> internal - members can be reached from within the same project only.
>
> protected internal - the same as internal, except that also classes which inherits from this class can reach it members, even from another project.
>
> private - can only be reached by members from the same class. This is the most restrictive visibility. Classes and structs are by default set to private visibility.